# extras(notification text) doesn't get passed

Tags: java, android-intent, notifications

the extras ( a notification text) doesn't get passed to the textView, (the text view appears empty), what's the problem?
here's the related code:

AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver :
https://textuploader.com/1j851

Notification Activity( that should show the text):
https://textuploader.com/1j85j

my main activity:
https://textuploader.com/1j8tr

please excuse me if I did any stupid mistakes, I'm new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is your problem here. You pass the wrong value here. You make an object `i` but you are using `intent` object.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context,
            NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("message",x);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

So use like this below.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context,
            NotificationActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); //i 
    i.putExtra("message",x); //i
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```